# findViewById with PhotoView library problem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-photoview

I am trying to use PhotoView [library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) with Kotlin.

But when I try to get photoView as in exaple:

```
val photoView = mView.findViewById<PhotoView>(R.id.zoomImageView)
```

I got error "Type argument is not within its bounds.
Expected:
View!
Found:
PhotoView"

Comment: you don't need to use `findViewById` in kotlin.

Comment: @Tony it's not true. In majority of the cases, yes, you no needed. But sometimes you have to use it (e.g. in own views or fragments)

Answer (score 3):

In your case issue is with typecasting either remove the typecasting or do something like this:

There are two ways you can fix this:

1)`val photoView= mView.findViewById(R.id.zoomImageView)`

2)`val photoView:PhotoView= mView.findViewById(R.id.zoomImageView) as PhotoView`

Comment: Indeed the IDE should show `photoView` as `View`. Cast it using `as PhotoView`.

Comment: Ok then the issue seems to be with type casting you should let kotlin automatically decide the type so now try implementing the first solution i gave without typecast it should solve it